# Add current login user name and/or avatar to Appbar

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there a good way to add current login user full name and/or avatar to AppBar?

I looked at the documentation but couldn't find the way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to make a custom app for that and implement a custom AppBar by yourself. You can find more info about this in the documentation [here](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html)